# Laravel Fortify 2 factor authentication valid for x days

Tags: laravel, fortify, two-factor-authentication, laravel-fortify

I’ve implemented 2-factor authentication with Laravel Fortify and was wondering if it’s possible to allow a period of x days before prompting the user for the 2-factor step again if they are still on the same IP address?

All answers or maybe ideas will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!